# How filter() and get() are implemented in GAE queries?

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I basically want to know how GAE has implemented its indexing, I'm familiar with indexing such as B+ trees and wonder if e.g. the filter() method uses a B+ tree for its implementation? Can I see this implementation in the appengine code for the SDK since it is Open Source? Is the get() and get_by_id() functions implemented using hashing to make it O(1)`Is the filter function O(log(n)) since one might think it uses a B+ tree where lookups are O(log(n))?

Thanks for any insight

Comment: BigTable is not open source, and the datastore in the SDK is very different from the one in production.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the long answer is my talk from a few years ago: [Under the Covers of the Google App Engine Datastore](http://sites.google.com/site/io/under-the-covers-of-the-google-app-engine-datastore). you'll also be interested in the [Bigtable paper](http://research.google.com/archive/bigtable.html) and [Megastore paper](http://research.google.com/pubs/pub36971.html).

the short answer is, query filtering is implemented via both single-property and multi-property (aka composite) indices. the query planner picks one or more to scan and merge densely, ie all or almost all scanned index rows correspond to a valid result for the query. details in my talk.

get() is implemented as a bigtable single row lookup. it's somewhere between O(1) and O(log(n)), with small constant factors since the log(n) part usually happens entirely in memory. details in the bigtable paper.